# How to configure HTML Tidy with PHP 7.0 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, html, ubuntu-14.04, htmltidy

Is anyone know how to configure HTML Tidy in Ubuntu 14.04?

So that it can be use in PHP 7.0.

What i've done is execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-tidy
```

but tidy still not work with php when i use `tidy_parse_string()`.

Comment: can you check if it's enabled or not? check by <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim I don't see "Tidy" in my phpinfo(), but I already run above command. I think after run apt-get, it will be automatically configured, right?

Comment: For my case, it was automatically configured and working fine.

Comment: can you share the content of your `phpinfo()` output?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP module needs to be enabled after installing.  After enabling, apache will need to be restarted to pick up the change.  Therefore, the following two commands are necessary:

```
$ sudo phpenmod tidy
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Please, add some description.